# Nodejs - Difference between require('module') and require('module').db?

Tags: node.js

```
//module.js
exports.doA = function(callback) {
   db.asyncConnect(/* connect options */, function(err, database) {
       if(err == null) {
           exports.db = database;
       }
   });
}

exports.db = null;

// test1.js
var mydb = require('module');
console.log(mydb);

// test2.js
var db = require('module').db;
console.log(db);
```

How is var `mydb = require('module');` different from var `mydb = require('module').db;` ?

**Update**: Updating with the code and behavior I am observing

```
// file: db.js
exports.init = function (start_server){
    MongoClient.connect(url, {
            db: {
                raw: true
            },
            server: {
                poolSize: 5
            }
        },
        function(err, database) {
            exports.db = database;
            if(err == null)
            start_server();
        }
    );
}

exports.db = null;
```

.

```
// file: test.js
var mongodb = require('./db.js');
var db = require('./db.js').db;

console.log("MongoDb " + mongodb.db);
console.log("DB " + db);
```

**Output**:
MongoDb [object Object]
DB null

Q. The variable `db` is coming out to be null but `mongodb.db` is having values? 
Even if I assign the value of `mongodb.db` in a variable, the value is coming out to be null.

Answer (score 2):

```
var mydb = require('module');
```

This gets the entire module.

```
var mydb = require('module').db;
```

This gets the property `db` of the object that the module returns.

The downside to the latter part is that you can't access the "parent" object anymore, ie. whatever is returned from the `.db` call, will be what you get and nothing else.

Quick example:

```
//some_module.js

var SomeModule = {
    db: function () {
        console.log("hello");
    }
};
module.exports = SomeModule;

//some_other_module.js
var SomeModule = require('./some_module.js');
console.log(SomeModule); // [Object object]

var SomeDB = require('./some_module.js').db;
console.log(SomeDB); // function () {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically different

```
var mydb = require('module');
```

That means every `object` that you export will be called/ imported. `mydb.doA` and `mydb.db` are available.

```
var db = require('module').db;
```

Only `db` object is called/ imported to your code. Different from first example, `db` it self is like `mydb.db` in the first example.